# how to get name from url dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**How to get a part of the url?**

query to be made:

```
$name = 'LeSant'; // (from url dinamic) //
$event = Dias::where('name', $name)->first();
```

[image]

How can I get `name` from the url? /event/**LeSant**

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#required-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are declared this route. You can specify model parameter and with laravel route binding you can inject model in your controller method https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#customizing-the-key

In `routes/web.php`:

```php
Route::get('/events/{event:name}', [EventController::class, 'show']);
```

And in `EventController` controller you can use something like that:

```php
public function show(Event $event)
{
    // do something with $event
}
```

Or if it not suits to you can get last element from `request()->segments()`

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do that. You can use request helper for it. Below two ways with requesthelper:

1. `request()->segment(count(request()->segments()))`
2. `last(request()->segments())`